# Spezifiziert "in" oder spezifiziert "von"?

Tags: word-usage

In verschiedenen Texten lese ich das Wort "spezifiziert" öfter mal sowohl mit "in" als auch mit "von" als Präpostion:

> XY ist **in** der Norm AB spezifiziert.

oder

> XY ist **von** der Norm AB spezifiziert.

Ich frage mich, ob eine von beiden Formulierungen grammatikalisch richtig oder falsch ist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich würde nach einem *spezifiziert von* das Gremium als den Urheber der Spezifikation erwarten, also z. B. IETF, ISO, W3C.

*Spezifiziert in* gibt die Norm oder (ggf. öffentlich verfügbare) Spezifikation selbst an.

Answer (score 2):

**Spoiler:**

> XY ist **durch** die Norm spezifiziert.

---

Grammatikalisch sind die Sätze

> (*1*) XY ist **in** der Norm AB spezifiziert.
>
> (*2*) XY ist **von** der Norm AB spezifiziert.

beide richtig. Die Frage ist eher, ob einer von ihnen vielleicht sinnfrei wäre.

Mein erster Impuls war, Satz (*1*) als sinnfrei und Satz (*2*) als sinnvoll zu interpretieren, denn eine Norm ist ja eine Regel, die als ein Ganzes auf das Zuregelnde wirkt.

> Das zu regelnde XY ist **von** der Regel AB geregelt.

Anders wäre es, wenn eine Norm ein Regelwerk wäre, das selbst aus mehreren Regeln bestünde.

> Das zu regelnde XY ist **in** der Norm AB durch die Regeln 1, 4, und 7 geregelt.

Nun könnte man aber auch fragen: *Wer spezifiziert* hier eigentlich? In Satz (*2*) tritt die Norm als Akteur auf - doch sind es nicht Menschen, die **durch** Normen etwas spezifizieren?

> XY wurde **von** Herrn Mustermann **durch** die Norm AB spezifiziert.

Aufgrund dieser Überlegung würde ich die Formulierung im Spoiler oben verwenden.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Auf die Formulierung mit "durch" bin ich gar nicht gekommen...

Comment: Zumindest beim DIN bezeichnet der Begriff „Norm“ nicht eine einzelne Regel, sondern ein Regelwerk, das als Gesamtheit publiziert wird. Daher finde ich „in der Norm“ richtig.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Mag sein, dann nenne es von mir aus um. Ich habe nur nach synonyme Begriffe für _Norm_ und den einzelnen in einer Norm gelisteten Dingen gesucht, und mir fiel spontan _Regel_ für das eine ein. Sei's drum, für die Fragestellung ist das von mir verwendete Synonym völlig irrelevant. Es geht dorch darum, ob es **in** der, **von** der oder eben **durch** die Norm heißen sollte. Und es ist üblicherweise nun mal so, dass XY _**durch** die Norm als Ganzes_, und nicht nur _durch eine Teilmenge der **in** der Norm gelisteten Regeln_ - wenn du sie so nennen möchtest -, spezifiziert wird.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn die Norm ein Regelwerk ist, ist **in** völlig richtig, da dann die Spezifikation in der Norm zu finden ist. Das Wort **von** ist auf jeden Fall richtig, da es ein Zustandspassiv bildet, also bloß eine Umformung:

> Die Norm AB spezifiziert XY

und daher:

> XY ist **von** der Norm XY spezifiziert.

Daher ist üblicherweise beides korrekt.

Answer (score 0):

Ich sehe Beides als richtig an, und zwar mit folgender Interpretation:

> XY ist in der Norm AB spezifiziert.

*Die Norm AB* bezeichnet das Dokument, das Schriftstück, in dem die Regeln, welche für eine Konformität mit der Norm ausschlaggebend sind, niedergeschrieben sind.

> XY ist von der Norm AB spezifiziert.

*Die Norm AB* bezeichnet hier die in der Norm zusammengefassten Regeln, welche hier sozusagen als Akteur auftreten, indem sie durch ihre Existenz eine gewisse Wirkung entfalten.